# doctrine FindBy method with 'OR condition'?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is it possible to use **OR** statement in Doctrine **findBy()** method?

I want That the output Be like this :

```
SELECT * FROM `friends` WHERE userId=1 OR FriendId=1 ;
```

The code Now :

```
$user = $repository->findBy(array(
            'userId' => $this->getRequest()->getSession()->get('id')
    );
```

Answer (score 4):

I would just use DQL... Add a function like this to your repository:

```
public function findFriends($userId)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT f FROM Friends WHERE userId = :userId OR FriendId = :userId')
        ->setParameter('userId', $userId)
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

Or use the query builder instead of DQL:

```
public function findFriends($userId)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->from('Friends', 'f')
        ->where('f.userId = :userId')
        ->orWhere('f.friendId = :userId')
        ->setParameter('userId', $userId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

And then just use:

```
$user = $repository->findFriends($this->getRequest()->getSession()->get('id'));
```

Answer (score 3):

#### MongoDB specific syntax

You can use the `$or` and `$and` keys in the array you pass to `findBy`:

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getSession()->get('id');
$user = $repo->findBy(
    array(
        '$or' => array(
            array('userId' => $id),
            array('FriendId' => $id),
        ),
    );
);
```

### Using QueryBuilder:

But seeing as this is mongoDB specific, this probably doesn't answer your question. Using the queryBuilder, you could just write this:

```
$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('f')
    ->from('friends', 'f')//replace friends with the correct entity name
    ->where('f.userId = :uid')
    ->orWhere('f.FriendId = :fid')
    ->setParameter('uid', $id)
    ->setParameter('fid', $id);
$users = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult();//or more
```

You could build the `or` clause using querybuilder expressions instead, that would look something like this:

```
$qb->where(
        $qb->expr()->orX(
            $qb->expr()->eq('f.userId', ':uid'),
            $qb->expr()->eq('f.FriendId', ':fid')
        )
    )
    ->setParameter('uid', $id)
    ->setParameter('fid', $id);
```

[Here's some more info](http://findby.incorrectcode.site/doctrine-findby-with-or-condition/218659/)

Even though you're using the same value twice, you have to call `setParameter` twice. [The reason for this can be found here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-705)

Lastly, some more docs [on the `QueryBuilder` class](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

Comment: Have you tried either of your queries?  Neither will work.

Comment: @Cerad: I haven't, nor did I pay any attention to the fact that OP is probably _not_ using MongoDB. I've updated my answer

Comment: For me : Unrecognized field: $or