# Error in using findBy() method in Symfony3

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.2

I have a simple controller as following:

```
public function fetchDataAction($username){
    $user_email = $this -> getDoctrine()
        -> getRepository('AdminBundle:Users')
        -> findBy( array('username' => $username ), array('id' => 2));

    return $this -> render('AdminBundle:Admin:fetchData.html.twig', array('datas' => $user_email));
}
```

But in running the code I face the error:

```
Invalid order by orientation specified for AdminBundle\Entity\Users#userId
```

Passing one array to `findBy()` method, the code run errorlessly, But When I pass multiple arrays, It fails!

Where is the problem?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to append records that satisfy one of my conditions (OR operator) not all of my condition

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that second parameter to `findBy` is sort order. Passing `array('id' => 2)` as a sort order causes your error (if you've read it's text).

So the solution is to pass both filter criterias in one array:

```
-> findBy( array('username' => $username, 'id' => 2) );
```

Comment: I want records having `username = $username` OR records having `id = 2`. I think your recommendation give those records have `username = $username` AND records having `id = 2`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. In your case it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003492/doctrine-findby-method-with-or-condition

Comment: Thanks but links didn't help! You know I do according to Symfony document http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database but the result is not desirable.