# FindBy() method "or" / "and"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

How can I use an `or` in a `findBy` method.

Exemple : I have an entity with `id_user_one` and `id_user_two` and I want to search by a `findby` method all entities were `id = 1` for `id_user_one` or `id_user_two`.

Question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003492/doctrine-findby-method-with-or-condition) but no one find an response that works ... hope that is possible :)

P.S. : if you know how it works for `and` too I will be glad to know it :)

Comment: Have a look at Repositories, they're made for that: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/repository.html

Comment: `and` is a default behavoiur. Open a manual sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible to do that only using findBy. You either have to write a repository function yourself:

```
$repo->createQueryBuilder('e')
   ->andWhere('e.id_user_one = :user_id')
   ->orWhere('e.id_user_two = :user_id') // change to andWhere depending on your needs
   ->setParameter('user_id', 1)
   ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

or fetch the entities with two calls and then merge the results:

```
$collection1 = $repo->findBy(['id_user_one' => 1]);
$collection2 = $repo->findBy(['id_user_two' => 1]);
$collection3 = new ArrayCollection(
    array_merge($collection1->toArray(), $collection2->toArray())
);
```

For your ps: `$result = $repo->findBy(['id_user_one' => 1, 'id_user_two' => 1]);`

Comment: Thx a lot :) (i dind't need to convert the collection1 and 2 toArray())

Comment: Is it possible for your entity to have the same id for user_one and user_two? If that's the case be carefull: the same entity could appear twice in collection3.